# Entity Framework : an existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host

Tags: c#, sql-server, wpf, entity-framework

I am using Entity Framework 6.2.0 with my WCF service hosted in IIS. I am getting this error when trying to eager load related table data. I have two tables `Product` and `Category` joined by `CategoryID`.

Trying to fetch products data and their related `category Name` but getting that error (I have tried almost every solution on web from last 24 hours).

```
public List<Product> GetAllProducts(int start, int end)
{
    return _context.Products.Include(x=>x.Category).ToList();
}
```

I have also set following properties to false.

```
public Intelliventory_DBEntities()
    : base("name=Intelliventory_DBEntities")
{
    this.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
    this.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
}
```

**App.config**

```
<configuration>
    <system.serviceModel>
        <bindings>
            <basicHttpBinding>
                <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IIntelliventoryService" 
                         closeTimeout="10:01:00" openTimeout="10:01:00" 
                         receiveTimeout="10:10:00" sendTimeout="10:01:00" 
                         allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" 
                         maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" 
                         maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647"
                         useDefaultWebProxy="true">
                    <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" 
                                  maxStringContentLength="2147483647"
                                  maxArrayLength="2147483647"    
                                  maxBytesPerRead="2147483647"
                                  maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
                </binding>
            </basicHttpBinding>
        </bindings>
        <behaviors>
            <endpointBehaviors>
                <behavior name="ServiceBehavior">
                     <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483647"/>
                </behavior>
            </endpointBehaviors>
        </behaviors>
        <client>
            <endpoint name="BasicHttpBinding_IIntelliventoryService" 
                address="http://localhost:5050/IntelliventoryService.svc"
                behaviorConfiguration="ServiceBehavior"  
                binding="basicHttpBinding" 
                bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IIntelliventoryService"
                contract="IntelliventoryService.IIntelliventoryService" />
        </client>
    </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

**Web.Config**

```
<configuration>
    <configSections>
        <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
    </configSections>
    <appSettings>
        <add key="aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext" value="true" />
    </appSettings>
    <system.web>
        <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.8" />
        <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.8" />
    </system.web>
    <system.serviceModel>
        <bindings>
            <basicHttpBinding>
                <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IIntelliventoryService" 
                         closeTimeout="10:01:00" openTimeout="10:01:00" 
                         receiveTimeout="10:10:00" sendTimeout="10:01:00" 
                         allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" 
                         maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" 
                         maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647"
                         useDefaultWebProxy="true">
                    <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" 
                                  maxStringContentLength="2147483647"
                                  maxArrayLength="2147483647" 
                                  maxBytesPerRead="2147483647"
                                  maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
                </binding>
            </basicHttpBinding>
        </bindings>
        <behaviors>
            <serviceBehaviors>
                <behavior>
                    <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph ="2147483647"/>
                    <serviceThrottling maxConcurrentCalls="16" maxConcurrentInstances="26" maxConcurrentSessions="10" />
                    <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true" />
                    <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
                </behavior>
            </serviceBehaviors>
        </behaviors>
        <protocolMapping>
            <add binding="basicHttpsBinding" scheme="https" />
        </protocolMapping>
        <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
        </system.serviceModel>
    <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
    <directoryBrowse enabled="true" />
  </system.webServer>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
      <parameters>
        <parameter value="mssqllocaldb" />
      </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
<connectionStrings>
  <add name="Intelliventory_DBEntities" 
                        connectionString="metadata=res://*/ADOModel.csdl|res://*/ADOModel.ssdl|res://*/ADOModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;
                        provider connection string=&quot;data source=RAO-HAMMAS-PC;initial catalog=Intelliventory_DB;persist security info=True;
                        user id=admin;password=admin;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" 
                        providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
</connectionStrings></configuration>
```

I don't get this error when i don't eager load category table.

Also if I try to load just specific column, I get this error.

```
_context.Products.Include(x=>x.Category.CategoryName).ToList();
```

> A specified Include path is not valid. The EntityType 'Intelliventory_DBModel.Category' does not declare a navigation

**Category Table from Db Context**

```
public int CategoryID { get; set; }
public string CategoryName { get; set; }
```

**Product Table from Db Context**

```
public partial class Product
{
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
    public Product()
    {
        this.Purchases = new HashSet<Purchase>();
    }

    public int ProductID { get; set; }
    public string ProductName { get; set; }
    public int CategoryID { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public double Quantity { get; set; }
    public string Model { get; set; }
    public string Details { get; set; }
    public double SellPrice { get; set; }
    public double PurchasePrice { get; set; }
    public int SupplierID { get; set; }
    public Nullable<double> PaidAmount { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> NoOfSales { get; set; }
    public Nullable<double> DueAmountToPay { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> ExpiryDate { get; set; }

    public virtual Category Category { get; set; }
    public virtual Supplier Supplier { get; set; }
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<Purchase> Purchases { get; set; }
}
```

As **@Andy** pointed that Category is not ICollection also Supplier is not ICollection but Purchases is ICollection. But it was all auto generated. Did i do something wrong ?

[image]

**This is what happens during data fetch event (SSMS Live Event)**

[image]

**Update: I created a console app and directly used EF and it worked**

[image]

> **But again when i used WCF in this console app to fetch Products, i got same error !**

**StackTrace of Exception**

```
System.ComponentModel.AsyncCompletedEventArgs.RaiseExceptionIfNecessary()
   at Intelliventory.IntelliventoryService.GetAllProductsCompletedEventArgs.get_Result() in E:\\2- Development\\2-NATIVE WORLD\\Projects\\Intelliventory\\Intelliventory\\Connected Services\\IntelliventoryService\\Reference.cs:line 321
   at Intelliventory.UserControls.ProductControl.ClientOnGetAllProductsCompleted(Object sender, GetAllProductsCompletedEventArgs e) in E:\\2- Development\\2-NATIVE WORLD\\Projects\\Intelliventory\\Intelliventory\\UserControls\\ProductControl.xaml.cs:line 89
   at Intelliventory.IntelliventoryService.IntelliventoryServiceClient.OnGetAllProductsCompleted(Object state) in E:\\2- Development\\2-NATIVE WORLD\\Projects\\Intelliventory\\Intelliventory\\Connected Services\\IntelliventoryService\\Reference.cs:line 1082
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.TryCatchWhen(Object source, Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs, Delegate catchHandler)
   at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.InvokeImpl()
   at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.InvokeInSecurityContext(Object state)
   at MS.Internal.CulturePreservingExecutionContext.CallbackWrapper(Object obj)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at MS.Internal.CulturePreservingExecutionContext.Run(CulturePreservingExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.Invoke()
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.ProcessQueue()
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.WndProcHook(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)
   at MS.Win32.HwndWrapper.WndProc(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)
   at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.DispatcherCallbackOperation(Object o)
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.TryCatchWhen(Object source, Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs, Delegate catchHandler)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.LegacyInvokeImpl(DispatcherPriority priority, TimeSpan timeout, Delegate method, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
   at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.SubclassWndProc(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
   at MS.Win32.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessage(MSG& msg)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrameImpl(DispatcherFrame frame)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrame(DispatcherFrame frame)
   at System.Windows.Application.RunDispatcher(Object ignore)
   at System.Windows.Application.RunInternal(Window window)
   at System.Windows.Application.Run(Window window)
   at System.Windows.Application.Run()
   at Intelliventory.App.Main()
```

**All three Exceptions !**

[image]
[image]
[image]

**Update: i have got the exception details (Category contains Cycles)**

> 'IntelliventoryWcfService.Category' contains cycles and cannot be serialized if reference tracking is disabled

[image]

Comment: Where is the database located?  The error indicates the application could not connect to the database.  The config shows :  address="http://localhost:5050/IntelliventoryService.svc".  So is the database on the IIS server or someplace else?  On a IIS server the application is run with GUEST privileges and the connection may be denied due to the owner of the connection.

Comment: So why do you try to include `x.Category.Category`? Seeing your model it shouldn't even compile.

Comment: @jdweng yes it is hosted in IIS i have mentioned that. and why other features work fine ? even i mean if i remove include thing still it works fine ?

Comment: @GertArnold sir ! why should not it compile ? it was all auto generated ..i did nothing .. Category and Products are related with CategoryId. and i am trying to get categoryName when fetching products ! just that .. i used to do that and i guess it work like that ...can you please tell me what looks wrong ?

Comment: Why shouldn't it compile? You knew, because you removed a typo. The first exception is probably caused by cyclic references which causes a stackoverflow exception in the serializer. That's a very common error when getting EF object graphs.

Comment: @GertArnold sir i am reading about it now ! but if i removed it it was also unintentionally (to be honest).. but i am stuck here and still getting same error ..can you spot the problem ?

Comment: Do the other feature access the same database tables in the same database?

Comment: @jdweng yeah obv ! but right now i just fetch Products with related category but get this error !

Comment: Can you use SQL Server Management Studio to perform query on IIS?  Check the SQL Server for error messages.  Check Event Viewer on IIS for errors.  You are having a connection issue probably due to credentials.

Comment: @jdweng i dont think it's a connection issue ! plus i am using sql credentials to login ..and other features works fine. even if i don't include categories then products are fetched

Comment: When you are on a IIS the credentials are using GUEST account.  Try changing the app on IIS to run as Admin and see if the error goes away.

Comment: See windows authentication at : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/iis/index?view=aspnetcore-2.2

Comment: how can i change it to run as admin ?

Comment: @jdweng and if thats a connection issue why other function working fine ? error occur when i use `Include` :(

Comment: Did you answer the question I asked : Do the other feature access the same database tables in the same database?

Comment: @jdweng yes other features access same database and same tables in same application .

Comment: Are you still getting the "forcibly closed" error?

Comment: @jdweng yeah from last 1 day i am getting same error :( sad life ....

Comment: Does not make any sense that you can access the database with other commands and then get the forcibly closed error unless you have more than one connection string.  The forcibly closed error occurs when the connection is made.  An existing connection when you do a query will not cause the error.  I suspect you are making multiple connections.

Comment: @jdweng sir as you can see in y web.config only one connection string defined by Entity framework ! i have not used any other connection in my application ! also the error occurs only when i use `".Include(x=>x.category)"`. if i remove it no error ..:(

Comment: Also ! i am getting Category data with no error. when fetching only category data !`return _context.Categories.ToList();`..so there is no problem with category table :(

Comment: *can you spot the problem ?* -- Again: it's the serializer running into an endless loop because of cyclic references. Do some research on reference loop handling.

Comment: @GertArnold why exactly this works in my old project ? 100% exactly this ! why i dont see sir cyclic reference here ? it's simple fetching Products and their related Category from Category table. what's looping ?

Comment: What is the stack trace of the Exception?

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft Sir i have included StackTrace in question. Please see update.

Comment: That's the client's stack trace and exception.  And so I assume it's the client whose connection was forcibly closed.   We need to know what exception on the WCF Service is causing it to abort the connection.

Comment: How would we know that sir ? can you please tell me where to look now ?

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft i have updated ..included all three exceptions i am getting . Please check that .

Comment: Those are all client exceptions.  Some exception is happening in the WCF service and causing it to Abort the connection.  That’s the Exception and Stack Trace you need.

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft can you please tell me how to get the exception details ?

Comment: Debug the WCF service, or fix it to send the details to the client or log them.

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft hi sir ! i think i have finally found the real exception it's about cycles ..Please check the update . And kindly suggest me what can i do to resolve it ?

Comment: Turn off LazyLoading and make sure you don't load Product.Purchaces or Product.Supplier.

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft but sir i have had already turned it off in constructor ..

Comment: It's possible that the change tracker has "fixed-up" the relationship from previously-loaded entities.  So try adding .AsNoTracking() or narrowing your DbContext lifetime.

Comment: Cyclic references. I told you so. Turning off lazy loading doesn't help because the references are loaded. Even with AsNoTracking they will be loaded (at least some of them). The serializer must be told not to serialize reference loops.

Comment: @GertArnold yes sir you were 100 right ! but now what to do ? how to tell serializer not to serialize reference loops?

Comment: I don't know WCF well enough to tell you how. You may even have overridden the default serializer. You should be able to find posts on preventing serializer reference loops in WCF.

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft sir .AsNoTracking didn't work ....

Comment: Well, now you know the root cause.  Back to your simplified repro, and add stuff until it reproduces.

Comment: Thanks God !!! Finally i got it working.....:););) i used `[DataContract(IsReference = true)]` on category class to handle Cycle reference . Thank you so much al of you for helping and for your time :) stay blessed always

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So finally i found and solved the issue with the help of some really good people :)
Issue was

> 'IntelliventoryWcfService.Category' contains cycles and cannot be serialized if reference tracking is disabled

So, basically **Category** contained cycles or circular reference that was causing server to drop the connection. Solution is to put `[DataContract(IsReference = true)]` on Category class. So the class now look like this.

```
using System.Runtime.Serialization;

[DataContract(IsReference = true)]
public partial class Category
{
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
    public Category()
    {
        this.Products = new HashSet<Product>();
    }
    [DataMember]
    public int CategoryID { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string CategoryName { get; set; }

    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    [DataMember]
    public virtual ICollection<Product> Products { get; set; }
}
```

**Help Reference**: http://themvcclub.blogspot.com/2014/11/how-to-fix-WCF-Web-API-Error-contains-cycles-and-cannot-be-serialized-if-reference-tracking-is-disabled.html

Answer (score 0):

Include is supposed to be the name of the property contains your collection.

Instead of

```
  Products.Include(x=>x.Category.Category)
```

I think that should be:

```
  Products.Include(x=>x.Category)
```

Or

```
  Products.Include("Category")
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/querying/related-data

It seems there is only going to be one category associated with a Product so it should be a scalar property.

Comment: Both of these didn't work ! i have already tried that . still get same error. but if i remove include thing ..then it works !

Comment: You also have defined Category wrongly. See edit above.

Comment: thanks for response ! actually it was all auto generated ..i did nothing ..Please see my edit ! i have included full Product class that was generated

Comment: And interestingly. Purchases is ICollection but category is not ??? what should i do ? the modification ? can you please tell me ..

Comment: Why supplier and Category are not ICollection like Purchases ? something wrong i did with Foreign key mapping ? or what ? i am really confused...

Comment: It's the relationship that tells EF there's supposed to be a table linked on a foreign key. I think you must have made a mistake there when setting that relationship to Categories up.

Comment: sir i have attached image of relation table. can you spot the problem in relation ?

Comment: If it's supposed to be one single category associated with a product then what you have there looks ok.  However,  .Include() should work with a scalar property. So I can't see why .Include("Category") does not work.

Comment: That's the problem i am facing ! it used to work for my old project but now it is stuck here :(

Comment: If you always want to load Category. What happens if you edit your entity class and remove the Virtual from it?  ( No include ). It's that Virtual modifier tells EF to lazy load.

Comment: I removed Virtual Keyword and i still get same Error !